# Line wont split into array

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, io

When getting a line from a file and splitting it tells me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\service user\Desktop\cmd\main.py", line 94, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\service user\Desktop\cmd\main.py", line 66, in start
    e = f.split('/')
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My code is here:

```
if split[0] == "/mount":
            extract(split[1])
            with open("info.m") as f:
                f.readlines()
                print f
                e = f.split('/')
                newlang = Conlang(e[0],e[1],e[2],e[3])
                f.close()
                print "Mounted as %s" % (e[0])
```

It is greatly appreciated if you know why it wont split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you meant something like this:

```
with open("info.m") as f:
    # now we have a file object 'f', we want to iterate it's lines
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line
        e = line.split('/')
        # ... rest of code
```

This code will split `f`, which is a file object (also an iterator) to a list of lines. Then it will iterate that list and print every line (and more...).